# Array of polygons on MapView

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps

I am creating a `mapView` with coordinates being downloaded from a XML file. I already have the coordinates parsed out like I want them to be but right know I'm hard coding the them, I have two problems the first is what's the best way to feed the points an array of `GeoPoints`"From XML File"? The second issue is that I cannot get the polygons to separate. I have five coordinates for each polygon view. The issue is it is connecting the polygons as if it was one. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong or is there something else I need to be doing. Below is what I currently have any help would be appreciated.

Ok I have an update to my original question, I got the array part working from the xml using [Laire's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124584/howto-ontouch-on-a-paint-overlay-googlemaps). So all of the coordinate are being downloaded to the map from the xml file but the issues is they are connected as if it is one set of coordinates. see [image: map with polygons].

Here is the code that I have so fair in my mainActivity.java

```
public class MapViewActivity extends MapActivity {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> boslst;
MapView mapView; 
MapController mapcontrol;
GeoPoint p;
Polygon polygon;

private static final class LatLonPoints extends GeoPoint { 
    public LatLonPoints(double latitude, double longitude) { 
        super((int) (latitude * 1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6)); 
    } 
} 
public static BigDecimal round(float d, int decimalPlace) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(d));
    bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);      
    return bd;

}  
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    String coordinates[] = {"35.20418", "-89.86862"};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

    p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6), 
            (int) (lng * 1E6));

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapcontrol = mapView.getController();
    mapcontrol.animateTo(p);
    mapcontrol.setZoom(10);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    ArrayList<GeoPoint> points = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    try {

        URL url = new URL(
                "my url");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Section");


        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            Element locElement = (Element) node;
            NodeList nameList = locElement.getElementsByTagName("coords");


            int locationCount = nameList.getLength();

        for (int j = 0; j < nameList.getLength(); j++) {

            Node nodel = nameList.item(j);

            Element fstElement = (Element) nodel;
            NodeList nameL = fstElement.getElementsByTagName("coords");
            Element nameE = (Element) nameL.item(0);
            nameL = nameE.getChildNodes();

            String latit = ((Node) nameL.item(0)).getNodeValue();
            String[] latt = latit.split(",");
            BigDecimal latitude = round(Float.parseFloat(latt[0]),5);
            BigDecimal longitude = round(Float.parseFloat(latt[1]),5);


            double Lat = latitude.doubleValue();
            double Long =  longitude.doubleValue();


            points.add(new LatLonPoints(Lat,Long));
            polygon = new Polygon(points);
      }
            polygon = new Polygon(points);

        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("APP","Failed", e);
    }        

    mapView.getOverlays().clear();
    mapView.getOverlays().add(polygon);
    mapView.invalidate();
}
```

Polygon.java

```
public class Polygon extends Overlay {
ArrayList<GeoPoint> geoPoints;

public Polygon(ArrayList<GeoPoint> points){
    geoPoints = points;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow){
    //Set the color and style
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#88ff0000"));
    paint.setAlpha(50);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    //Create path and add points
    Path path = new Path();
    Point firstPoint = new Point();
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPoints.get(0), firstPoint);
    path.moveTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);

    for(int i = 1; i < geoPoints.size(); ++i){
        Point nextPoint = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPoints.get(i), nextPoint);
        path.lineTo(nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);
    }

    //Close polygon
    path.lineTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
    path.setLastPoint(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

 }
 }
```

So my question what do I have to do to get the polygon to build one at a time and not act as one?

Comment: what do you mean "not act as one"?

Comment: if you look at the image is showing the polygons in the correct locations but a line is leaving each one and going to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to change this:

```
//Close polygon
path.lineTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
path.setLastPoint(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
```

to this:

```
    //Close polygon
    path.lineTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
    path.setLastPoint(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    path.close();
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
```

Closing the Path at the end and returns you to your original point.

Comment: I think my problem is in the loop, I did a count on the geoPoints and it returned 35. in my xml document I have 7 sets of 5 lat and longs. What should be happening is after every 5 it creates the polygon not taking the 35 and creating it.